Is it possible to remove incorrectly pushed git tags?
I somehow incorrectly pushed all tags on by branch to remote by following command:
git push -u --tags origin mybranch

I wonder if it is possible to revert effect of this operation in remote side or not.

DId you overwrite/re-set any tags on the remote, or simply push new tags only? Also, options for damage-recovery depend on the git remote server implementation you're using (e.g. simply restore from a backup if possible, or if your git server uses a strictly append-only storage, so you could rollback - also does/did your client-side git have any kind of logging or anything, so you know which tags were pushed?)

@Amadan that method deletes a single tag if my understanding is correct. But Here I have a whole set of tags.

So use the "delete a single tag" mechanism, but in a shell script loop over the names of all the erroneous tags.

Indeed. I am not aware of any other method, unless you have the remote server under your control and it has logs or backups, as Dai mentioned; but most of us just work with remotes not under our control, like GitHub.
